# Javascript AppendChild Issue

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, javascript-objects

**UPDATED WITH FULL CODE**

I'm trying to dynamically add a div onto some other DIV's stored in an array

The array which contains DIV's is named `categoryData` which contains an attribute with its `category name`

The shop-row div's (categoryData) is empty at the beginning.

I've got another array which contains the product object stored in an array called 
`storeCategoryData` 
The product object is in the following format,

```
{CategoryName:categoryname,StoreObject:store_clearfix} // store_clearfix is another div
```

I'm trying to add the `StoreObject` into the DIV categoryData.
Unfortunately some objects get added and not the others. I can figure out what i'm doing wrong here. Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks!

I tried doing everything possible. Still no luck :(

```
 var store_list = document.getElementsByClassName("shop-list")[0];


if(data['stores']!=null && data['stores'] !== typeof undefined){

    var numstores = Object.keys(data["stores"]).length;
    var count = 0;

    while (count < numstores) {

        var categories = data["stores"][count].Categories;
        var catcount = categories.length;
        var c=0;

        while(c<catcount){
            var cat = categories[c];

            if (!(storeCategories.indexOf(cat) > -1)) {

                var category_element = document.createElement("li");
                if(count==0 && c==0){
                    category_element.className="active";
                }
                var clickable = document.createElement("a");
                clickable.href = "#";
                clickable.innerText = cat;
                clickable.setAttribute("category-data", cat);
                storeCategories.push(cat);
                category_element.appendChild(clickable);
                category_list.appendChild(category_element);


                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.className = "shop-row";
                div.setAttribute("category-name", cat);
                categoryData.push(div);
            }

            c++;
        }

        count++;
    }

    count = 0;

    while (count < numstores) {

        var StoreId = data["stores"][count].StoreId;
        var WebsiteUrl = data["stores"][count].WebsiteUrl;
        var LogoUrl = data["stores"][count].LogoUrl;
        var categories = data["stores"][count].Categories;


        var store_clearfix = document.createElement("div");
        store_clearfix.className = "single-products-catagory clearfix";

        var store_atag =  document.createElement("a");
        store_atag.className = "home-shop";
        store_atag.href = WebsiteUrl;

        var store_img = document.createElement("img");
        store_img.className = "shop-icon";
        store_img.src = LogoUrl;
        store_img.alt = StoreId;

        store_atag.appendChild(store_img);
        store_clearfix.appendChild(store_atag);


        c=0;
        catcount = categories.length;
        while(c<catcount){
            var categoryname = categories[c];
            var i = 0;
            var datacount = categoryData.length;
            while(i<datacount){

                var datarow = categoryData[i];
                if(categoryname==datarow.getAttribute("category-name")) {
                    var storeObj = {CategoryName:categoryname,StoreObject:store_clearfix};
                    storeCategoryData.push(storeObj);
                    break;
                }

                i++;

            }

            c++;
        }


        count++;

    }


    categories_tab.appendChild(category_list);

    i=0;
    for (i = 0; i < categoryData.length; i++) {
        var div = categoryData[i];
        console.log(div);

        var name = div.getAttribute("category-name");

        var c;
        for (c = 0; c < storeCategoryData.length; c++) {
            console.log(storeCategoryData[c].CategoryName);
            if(storeCategoryData[c].CategoryName==name){
                console.log(storeCategoryData[c].StoreObject);
                div.appendChild(storeCategoryData[c].StoreObject);
           }

        }

        console.log("Finished "+name );
        console.log(div);
        store_list.appendChild(div);

    }

}
```

**Example variable `data` defined as follows**

```
{
"status": "success",
"stores": [
    {
        "StoreId": "randomStore",
        "WebsiteUrl": "https://abcd.com",
        "LogoUrl": "https://abcd.come",
        "Categories": [
            "ALL",
            "MENS",
            "WOMENS"
        ]
    },
    {
        "StoreId": "someStoreId",
        "WebsiteUrl": "https://someurl.com",
        "LogoUrl": "https://someLogo.com",
        "Categories": [
            "MENS"
        ]
    }
  ] 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you create a stack snippet or jsfiddle? without your HTML code it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I agree with Munim Munna 'it's not clear what you are asking', your code is not correct, when I'm trying to run this on JSFiddle I'm getting multiple ReferenceError: {propertyName} is not defined. This is JSFiddle working example. https://jsfiddle.net/c3ozfvry/ . Provide what you was expecting and what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are facing here is caused by the following behavior:

> The Node.appendChild() method adds a node to the end of the list of
>   children of a specified parent node. If the given child is a reference
>   to an existing node in the document, appendChild() moves it from its
>   current position to the new position ([MDN: Node.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild))

What this means is that **[`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)** will remove the node if already present in the DOM, which is what we are seeing here. This can be easily solved by creating a deep clone of the node first using **[`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)**, before appending it to the target div, as follows:

```
var clone = storeCategoryData[c].StoreObject.cloneNode(true);
div.appendChild(clone);
```

You can also refer to the snippet below for a working example:

```js
var categories_tab = document.getElementById('category-tab');
var store_list = document.getElementById('store-list');
var storeCategories = [];
var storeCategoryData = [];
var data = {
  "status": "success",
  "stores": [{
      "StoreId": "randomStore",
      "WebsiteUrl": "https://abcd.com",
      "LogoUrl": "https://abcd.come",
      "Categories": [
        "ALL",
        "MENS",
        "WOMENS"
      ]
    },
    {
      "StoreId": "someStoreId",
      "WebsiteUrl": "https://someurl.com",
      "LogoUrl": "https://someLogo.com",
      "Categories": [
        "MENS"
      ]
    }
  ]
};

var categoryData = [];

var category_list = document.createElement("ul");

if (data['stores'] != null && data['stores'] !== typeof undefined) {

  var numstores = Object.keys(data["stores"]).length;
  var count = 0;

  while (count < numstores) {

    var categories = data["stores"][count].Categories;
    var catcount = categories.length;
    var c = 0;

    while (c < catcount) {
      var cat = categories[c];

      if (!(storeCategories.indexOf(cat) > -1)) {

        var category_element = document.createElement("li");
        if (count == 0 && c == 0) {
          category_element.className = "active";
        }
        var clickable = document.createElement("a");
        clickable.href = "#";
        clickable.innerText = cat;
        clickable.setAttribute("category-data", cat);
        storeCategories.push(cat);
        category_element.appendChild(clickable);
        category_list.appendChild(category_element);


        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.className = "shop-row";
        div.setAttribute("category-name", cat);
        categoryData.push(div);
      }

      c++;
    }

    count++;
  }

  count = 0;

  while (count < numstores) {

    var StoreId = data["stores"][count].StoreId;
    var WebsiteUrl = data["stores"][count].WebsiteUrl;
    var LogoUrl = data["stores"][count].LogoUrl;
    var categories = data["stores"][count].Categories;


    var store_clearfix = document.createElement("div");
    store_clearfix.className = "single-products-catagory clearfix";

    var store_atag = document.createElement("a");
    store_atag.className = "home-shop";
    store_atag.href = WebsiteUrl;

    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.className = "shop-icon";
    var t = document.createTextNode(LogoUrl);
    p.appendChild(t)

    store_atag.appendChild(p);
    store_clearfix.appendChild(store_atag);


    c = 0;
    catcount = categories.length;
    while (c < catcount) {
      var categoryname = categories[c];
      var i = 0;
      var datacount = categoryData.length;
      while (i < datacount) {

        var datarow = categoryData[i];
        if (categoryname == datarow.getAttribute("category-name")) {
          var storeObj = {
            CategoryName: categoryname,
            StoreObject: store_clearfix
          };
          storeCategoryData.push(storeObj);
          break;
        }

        i++;

      }

      c++;
    }


    count++;

  }


  categories_tab.appendChild(category_list);

  i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < categoryData.length; i++) {
    var div = categoryData[i];
    console.log(div);

    var name = div.getAttribute("category-name");

    var c;
    for (c = 0; c < storeCategoryData.length; c++) {
      console.log(storeCategoryData[c].CategoryName);
      if (storeCategoryData[c].CategoryName == name) {
        console.log(storeCategoryData[c].StoreObject);
        var clone = storeCategoryData[c].StoreObject.cloneNode(true);
        div.appendChild(clone);
      }

    }

    console.log("Finished " + name);
    console.log(div);
    store_list.appendChild(div);

  }

}
```

```html
<div id="category-tab" style="min-height: 20px; border: 1px solid; padding: 10px"></div>
<div id="store-list" style="min-height: 20px; border: 1px solid green; padding: 10px; margin-top: 30px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not completely understand what you wrote there but as I can see you want to attach from the JSON string and not Node with appendChild.

```
var div = categoryData[i];
```

It should be something like this:

```
store_list.innerHTML += DIV;
```

I would not even start a while loop with NULL or empty array categoryData. I would outsource this in a function because if I want to call it dynamically again or first see if it's even available. storeCategoryData is an object and not an array ... etc

Comment: `categoryData` is not empty when being used, because the data is added to the array before being assigned onto `div`. Your solution of using innerHTML does not work.

Comment: I have a lot to do with this, but I do not see everything in your example. maybe it will help you if you look at my code here: digital.deutsches-museum.de/hitlist/

Comment: I'll give it a go. But note that div here is an actual node and not a string, because the append child does work. It does get appended but not every div that is supposed to get appended does. In this example only two divs get appended but if you look at the console you can see that 4 divs are supposed to get appended (single-product-category clearfix). Before i appened i printed the content to the console..

Answer (score -1):

I think the reason is that one store element can only be appended to only one category element, even it could belong to multiple categories.

========keep history below:====================

The log looks perfect to me. I can't see the problem.

You wrote the statement:

```
if(storeCategoryData[c].CategoryName==name)
```

So, some `StoreObject` are appended; others are not.

Comment: Check line 183 on the log, the object in line 175 in the log is not appended. I just don't get it! Why not?